# *** glibc detected *** /usr/sbin/httpd: free(): invalid pointer: 0x068977f0 ***

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, html, apc

Completely fresh install of CentOS and I've installed PHP, MySQL and Apache with all modules, when I first tried to run the service the following message is in the error_log followed by a memory map.

```
*** glibc detected *** /usr/sbin/httpd: free(): invalid pointer: 0x068977f0 ***
```

I've tried updating APC and even removing it as some seemed to have luck with that, 'service httpd status' yields

```
httpd dead but subsys locked
```

And I've tried many solutions to that problem without any luck, any help?

Comment: Have you installed Apache, MySQL and PHP via `yum` from the official repos or in any other way?

Comment: I used yum, the only repos I have enabled are epel (which may be the cause?) and plex/chrome which aren't likely to be the issue.